# Gitlab CE in Docker and gitlab-runner

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I installed Gitlab CE in docker container (using image gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest) and everything is working fine but I don't know how to install gitlab-runner. Is gitlab-runner should be installed in the same container as gitlab or maybe as separate container? If as separate container then how should it be connected to gitlab? I cannot find useful information. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GitLab runner can be installed in a cloud on a different continent to be exact. It's a REST service totally independent from the Gitlab itself. Run it anywhere you can, as a separate container on the same host, in a cloud, on your local computer, etc.

GitLab communicates with its runners using HTTPS protocol.

When you create a runner and run the [registration procedure](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/index.html), it asks for:

- the coordinator url (your GitLab instance URL)
- GitLab's token (think of it as a password)

You're done. The runner will register itself with your GitLab instance. Note from the support about the communication:

> Runners communicate with GitLab over HTTPS, entirely through connections initiated from the Runner to GitLab and never in reverse. The advantage here is that you can install a Runner behind a firewall and as long as the Runner has outbound access to GitLab.com it will work. From there, it really doesn’t matter which executor you use (Shell, Docker, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it now seems obvious.